# SQL: How to select items from a table with the highest percentage of change

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, max

Ok, I'm totally stumped.

I have a table GROCERY_PRICES.

In it there is data for GROCERY_ITEM, PRICE_IN_2012, and ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042.

I need to Write a SQL SELECT statement that finds the items having the highest percentage of price increase. And then sort by GROCERY_ITEM.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab the three items with the highest percentage of change over the time period using the data in the table.

This is the code I have, it returns all the data I need, but for every GROCERY_ITEM rather than the three items with the highest percentage of change.  I know it's 310 but I can't hardcode that number in.

```
SELECT grocery_item, 
       price_in_2012, 
       ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042, 
       sum((ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042 - PRICE_IN_2012) / PRICE_IN_2012) * 100 as Percent_Change
FROM grocery_prices 
GROUP BY grocery_item, 
         price_in_2012, 
         ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042
ORDER BY grocery_item;
```

I know I need to use a subquery, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Thanks.

EDIT:  Some sample data:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: What DBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...)?

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of sample data from your table? Maybe it's me but your `GROUP BY` makes no sense to me

Comment: @peterm I'm using Oracle SQL Developer, I had it tagged, but someone removed the tag apparently.

Comment: @petrem I'm not sure how to add the data from the table here... I'll try...`E_001 0.62 1.78 |
B_001 0.8 3.28 |
B_002 2.72 7.36 |
M_004 2.7 5.65 |
T_006 5.7 6.65 |
R_003 4 16.4 |
G_010 8 32.8`

Comment: So that would be, GROCERY_ITEM PRICE_IN_2012 ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042 |  GROCERY_ITEM PRICE_IN_2012 ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042 and so on.

Comment: is your grocery_prices table contains multiple entries of same grocery_item

Comment: @AshishJagtap it does not, refer to the image I just edited in to see the entire contents of the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT grocery_item, price_in_2012, estimated_price_in_2042, percent_change
  FROM
(
  SELECT grocery_item, price_in_2012, estimated_price_in_2042, 
         ROUND((estimated_price_in_2042 - price_in_2012) / price_in_2012 * 100, 2) AS percent_change,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ABS((estimated_price_in_2042 - price_in_2012) / price_in_2012 * 100) DESC) AS rank
    FROM grocery_prices t
) q
 WHERE rank <= 3;
```

Output:

```
| GROCERY_ITEM | PRICE_IN_2012 | ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042 | PERCENT_CHANGE |
|--------------|---------------|-------------------------|----------------|
|        B_001 |           0.8 |                    3.28 |            310 |
|        G_010 |             8 |                    32.8 |            310 |
|        R_003 |             4 |                    16.4 |            310 |
```

Depending on your needs you may want to use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT grocery_item, price_in_2012, estimated_price_in_2042, percent_change
  FROM
(
  SELECT grocery_item, price_in_2012, estimated_price_in_2042, 
         ROUND((estimated_price_in_2042 - price_in_2012) / price_in_2012 * 100, 2) AS percent_change,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ABS((estimated_price_in_2042 - price_in_2012) / price_in_2012 * 100) DESC) AS rank
    FROM grocery_prices t
) q
 WHERE rank <= 3;
```

Output:

```
| GROCERY_ITEM | PRICE_IN_2012 | ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042 | PERCENT_CHANGE |
|--------------|---------------|-------------------------|----------------|
|        B_001 |           0.8 |                    3.28 |            310 |
|        G_010 |             8 |                    32.8 |            310 |
|        R_003 |             4 |                    16.4 |            310 |
|        E_001 |          0.62 |                    1.78 |          187.1 |
|        B_002 |          2.72 |                    7.36 |         170.59 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7ae1/12)** demo

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  Oh, so if I wanted to select from percent_change, I have to list it earlier, THEN define what it contains in my subquery, among other things.  However I do have a question, how would you do it using the max function on the percent_change column?  I was trying to simply take the max value returned from my percentile equation, instead of returning the max, I'd simply get the values for every item, and not the three items with the max percent_change.

Comment: If you want to return TOP N, where N > 1, (TOP 3 in your case) rows from a set using only `MAX()` is insufficient. You have to use ranking by using order by + rownum or by using analytic windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER(), DENSE_RANK(), RANK()` or by using a correlated subquery with `COUNT()`.

Comment: So there isn't really a way to do it dynamically so that regardless of how many max values there are, you only get just those?

Comment: Why? It's totally dynamic. You just tell how many top records you want in the outer select.

Comment: Hrm, I see, well at any rate, your help will do just fine, I appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

top 3 items having the highest percentage of price increase

```
SELECT  GROCERY_ITEM,PRICE_IN_2012,ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042,
ROUND(((`ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042` - `PRICE_IN_2012`) / PRICE_IN_2012) * 100) AS Percent_Change
FROM grocery_prices AS itm
GROUP BY GROCERY_ITEM
ORDER BY Percent_Change DESC LIMIT 3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3471b/1)

hope this help you !

Comment: OP is using Oracle, not MySQL

Comment: sorry I thought it is in MySQL :(

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    im_employees a
where   (select count(distinct employee_id ) from im_employees where             employee_id>=a.employee_id)<=3;
```

this selects top 3 rows with max employee_id from im_employees table for me.

i think this will help you!!!

Comment: put percent_change instead of employee_id

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
select ROCERY_ITEM,PRICE_IN_2012,ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042,round((cast(ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042-PRICE_IN_2012 as numeric)/PRICE_IN_2012)*100,3)||'%' from GROCERY_PRICES order by round((cast(ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042-PRICE_IN_2012 as numeric)/PRICE_IN_2012)*100,3) desc limit 3;
```

in postgresql

in oracle

```
select rownum,ROCERY_ITEM,PRICE_IN_2012,ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042,round(((ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042-PRICE_IN_2012)/PRICE_IN_2012)*100,3)||'%' from GROCERY_PRICES  where rownum < 4 order by round((cast(ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2042-PRICE_IN_2012 as numeric)/PRICE_IN_2012)*100,3) desc;
```